# how to load phtml via ajax in magento admin panel

Tags: php, magento

How can phtml be loaded in magento admin panel via ajax?  Here are the details.

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\layout.xml :

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
            <reference name="product_tabs">
                <action method="addTab">
                    <name>My_custom_tab</name>
                    <block>listing/adminhtml_catalog_product_tab</block>
                </action>
            </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_new>
```

app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\mymodule\catalog\product\tab.phtml :

```
<div id="customer_info_tabs_customer_edit_tab_action_content">
    <div class="entry-edit">
        <div class="entry-edit-head">
            <h4 class="icon-head head-edit-form fieldset-legend">content</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="group_fields4" class="fieldset fieldset-wide">
            <div class="hor-scroll">
                content body
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

\app\code\local\Company\Mymodule\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Tab.php :

```
     <?php

class Company_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Tab extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('Mymodule/catalog/product/tab.phtml');
    }

    public function canShowTab()
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('product');
        //if on edit mode show the tab
        if ($product->getId()) {
            return true;
        }
        $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
        //if creating product with any attributes, show the tab
        if ($request->getParam('type')) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Listing');
    }

    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Listing');
    }

    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### It's normally loaded the custom tab module content which is not good.

I want the content is loaded via ajax. and i ended up googling it, by just adding this code to the Block->tab.php

```
 public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/custom', array('_current' => true));
    }

    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return 'ajax';
    }
```

How can i implement this ajax calls, when the listing is being triggered, the content is supposedly loaded via ajax. ? please help me my friends.

Comment: It works the same as in the frontend. Have you ever used AJAX in the shop?

Comment: fixed formatting, sepertation

Comment: This basically in backend add products or edit products under catalog management. i've used ajax before but magento uses its own ajax i want to know what it is, i know that the construct method above my block function will call automatically. i want to call that when the listing tab is being trigger. Bdw @hakre tnx for response.